# How to classify a point using Bayes classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, naive-bayes-classifier

The following 2 classes dataset is available:
$$
C_{1}=\left \{ 17,18,19,20,21 \right \},C_{2}=\left \{ 12,14 \right \}
$$
If we assume each class distribution is **gaussian**, To which class does **x=16** belong with **Bayes** classifier?

> In my opinion, we should use Bayes rule as the following:
> [image]
> But it takes a long time to calculate.
> [image]

Is another solution suggested?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. This is homework, isn't it? Please show your work and explain your difficulty. Tip: pay attention to the prior distribution.

Comment: @Erwan the difficulty is the gaussian distribution calculation. Is it true to use minimum distance classification?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "minimum distance classification" but no, it's probably not this. [Bayes classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Probabilistic_model) works by calculating two things: the conditional distribution $p(x|C_i)$ and the prior distribution $p(C_i)$. Did you calculate the mean and std. dev. of the two classes? If you do you may notice that $p(x=16|C_1)=p(x=16|C_2)$. Now can you calculate $p(C_i)$?

Comment: @Erwan I added my work and updated the question.

Comment: Your formula at the end is a bit difficult to read and you seem to have a 4 denominator instead of a 2 on the line before the last, but yes this seems correct. If you replace $x$ with 16 you can see that $(16-13)^2=(16-19)^2$, so $p(x=16|C1)=(x=16|C2)$... which means that you don't even need to calculate the exact value in order to find which class has the maximum posterior $p(C_i|x=16)$, since it depends only on the prior $p(C_i)$.

Comment: @Erwan I have a 4 denominator because $$\sigma _{1}^{2}=2$$ . $$p(x=16|C1)\neq p(x=16|C2)$$. If we calculate the distance between x=16 and mean of 2 classes and we choose the nearer class. what's your idea?

Comment: Oh sorry you're right, I made a mistake. Well then you need to calculate the values for both conditional probs and then multiply with the prior. The class which has the maximum result wins.